# SQL Server license from AWS Marketplace with ? cores

Tags: sql-server-2012, aws, license, sql-server-core

We are planning to buy a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition license from AWS Marketplace for our company. We have exhausted our previous licenses and we need to add a new region with SQL Server in cloud. This SQL instance will be in peer-to-peer replication with SQL instances in other regions. 
I also found Microsoft certified vendors who sell these licenses. These vendors clearly specify the number of cores for which SQL edition is licensed. In AWS Marketplace though, I don't find the number of cores specified. Does that mean if I use a R5.2X EC2 instance to host this SQL edition, it will be licensed (and billed) for 4 physical cores and if I use it in a R5.4x EC2 instance, it will be licensed(and billed) for 8 physical cores?
If anyone has experience buying SQL Server in AWS Marketplace, please advise.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The market place should sell you the number of core licenses you need based on the instance size you select at purchase time.

The price will be based on a per hour or per year rate that you choose at check out. That price is just for the software license, you are still required to pay for the ec2 instance run costs as well as the EBS volume(s) attached to the instance and the data transfer costs.

Example:[AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06XY2HKDH?qid=1558486618892&sr=0-45&ref_=srh_res_product_title#pdp-pricing)

In the screenshot below the selected instance of an m4.xl for a year the sql server licenses would cost $1607 however you would still need to pay the run cost for the m4.xl at $0.864 an hour plus $0.1 per GB of provisioned EBS storage.

If you were to assume as a simple example, you purchased the licenses for a year and ran the m4.xl on demand with an hourly rate of $0.864 and needed 100GB of EBS for the volume the cost would look:  1607 + ((720 hours per month * 12) * 0.864)+ ((0.1* 100GB) * 12 months) = $9,191.96 + (data transfer costs?)

[image: M4 Clarke]

Comment: Awesome. That is helpful. I also checked with AWS support and their reply was on similar lines(though a bit generic).

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Did support give you a reason why the run cost per hour would be higher in some cases then what the AWS listed price is per hour for the same instance?